# Rolling up data with nested maps in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

New to programming in a more "functional" style.  Normally I would write a series of nested foreach loops and `+=` to totals.

I have a data structure that looks like:

```
Map(
  "team1" ->
    Map(
      "2015" -> Map("wins" -> 30, "losses" -> 5),
      "2016" -> Map("wins" -> 3, "losses" -> 7)
    ),
  "team2" ->
    Map(
      "2015" -> Map("wins" -> 22, "losses" -> 1),
      "2016" -> Map("wins" -> 17, "losses" -> 4)
    )
)
```

What I want is a data structure that simply throws away the year information and adds wins/losses together by team.

```
Map(
  "team1" -> Map("wins" -> 33, "losses" -> 12),
  "team2" -> Map("wins" -> 39, "losses" -> 5)
)
```

I've been looking at [groupBy](http://markusjais.com/the-groupby-method-from-scalas-collection-library/) but that seems only be useful if I don't have this nested structure.

Any ideas?  Or is the more traditional imperative/foreach approach favorable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myMap.map(i => i._1 -> i._2.values.flatMap(_.toList).groupBy(_._1).map(i => i._1 -> i._2.map(_._2).sum))
```

> 1. get all values
> 2. `flatMap` to list
> 3. `groupBy` by key
> 4. get all the grouped values and sum

Comment: Thanks!  I ultimately modified your solution to `mapValues(_.values.flatten.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum))`, but this worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Using [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) you could do :

```
import cats.implicits._
// or
// import cats.instances.map._
// import cats.instances.int._
// import cats.syntax.foldable._

teams.mapValues(_.combineAll)
// Map(
//   team1 -> Map(wins -> 33, losses -> 12),
//   team2 -> Map(wins -> 39, losses -> 5)
// )
```

`combineAll` combines the wins/losses maps of every year using a `Monoid[Map[String, Int]]` instance (also provided by the Cats library, see [`Monoid` documentation](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/monoid.html)), which sums the `Int`s for every key.

Comment: Looks nice, only how does it choose `0/+` over `1/*` for `Int`? The latter is a monoid too.

Comment: @VictorMoroz The default `Monoid[Int]` in Cats (and Scalaz) uses addition

Answer (score 2):

Define a customized method to add two Maps by keys as:

```
def addMap(x: Map[String, Int], y: Map[String, Int]) = 
    x ++ y.map{ case (k, v) => (k, v + x.getOrElse(k, 0))}


m.mapValues(_.values.reduce(addMap(_, _)))
// res16: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = 
// Map(team1 -> Map(wins -> 33, losses -> 12), team2 -> Map(wins -> 39, losses -> 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.mapValues { _.toSeq
              .flatMap(_._2.toSeq)
              .groupBy(_._1)
              .mapValues(_.foldLeft(0)(_ + _._2)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scala>   val sourceMap = Map(
     |     "team1" ->
     |       Map(
     |         "2015" -> Map("wins" -> 30, "losses" -> 5),
     |         "2016" -> Map("wins" -> 3, "losses" -> 7)
     |       ),
     |     "team2" ->
     |       Map(
     |         "2015" -> Map("wins" -> 22, "losses" -> 1),
     |         "2016" -> Map("wins" -> 17, "losses" -> 4)
     |       )
     |   )
sourceMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]]] = Map(team1 -> Map(2015 -> Map(wins -> 30, losses -> 5), 2016 -> Map(wins -> 3, losses -> 7)), team2 -> Map(2015 -> Map(wins -> 22, losses -> 1), 2016 -> Map(wins -> 17, losses -> 4)))

scala>   sourceMap.map { case (team, innerMap) =>
     |     val outcomeGroups = innerMap.values.flatten.groupBy(_._1)
     |     team -> outcomeGroups.map { case (outcome, xs) =>
     |       val scores = xs.map(_._2).sum
     |       outcome -> scores
     |     }
     |   }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = Map(team1 -> Map(losses -> 12, wins -> 33), team2 -> Map(losses -> 5, wins -> 39))
```